# The Riddle Of Some

Tags: riddle, rhyme

This riddle requires no special knowledge in anything.

> I build up a world
>   from what is but none.
>   Most people might know me
>   but others know none.
>   Some people think magic is I
>   while some just don't wonder just why.
>   You know this thing all just too well
>   just answer the question you definitely can tell.

The answer will be told if none can figure it out. So try until you find a answer that fits the criteria. The title is a bit of a hint.

Hint One:

> This is more literal than you think, keep trying.

Hint Two:

> This answer is known to be a hobby to some

Hint Three:

> Said to be the Biggest advancement in our history.

BIG HINT:

> People use this as there job, like the StackExhange workers.

Comment: please post a hint instead of the answer right away if no one gets it

Comment: Added hints like you asked

Comment: <the answer> is not something of this century ... your 2nd hint is wrong :)

Comment: oh, thanks for telling me, ill make sure to change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> Code.

I build up a world
from what is but none.

> Software is produced from code.

Most people might know me
but others know none.

> Some can read/write code, others cannot.

Some people think magic is I
while some just don't wonder just why.

> Some like to code, others don't care to understand it.

You know this thing all just too well
just answer the question you definitely can tell.

> I'm actually doing basic coding now by interacting with Stack Overflow's user markup code to provide hidden answers, new lines, and other great SO features!

Comment: Very close, what makes the web

Comment: EXTREAMLY Close with that new guess

Comment: HTML Is just C___

Comment: Good job, since you gave HTML first, you won

Comment: @SmailBarkouch, Good Deal!!

Answer (score 2):

is it

> imagination

I build up a world
from what is but none.

> You can create entire worlds from your imagination and nothing else

Most people might know me
but others know none.

> some people are more imaginative than others

Some people think magic is I

> imagination is a kind of magic

while some just don't wonder just why.

> not sure about this line, it's worded a little oddly

You know this thing all just too well
just answer the question you definitely can tell.

> It takes imagination to answer the question, thus proving that you have it!

Comment: Good guess, but unluckly that isn't the answer. Look at the one you said was worded oddly. Its that for a reason, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Programming/coding/code

The above satisfy the conditions. Depends on what you have on mind as the puzzle is quite generic and may have multiple answers.

Comment: It may seem like that but there is something that fits all the quotas perfectly, may post the answer soon if no one gets it. Good job, but it is more realistic than you think

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Your updated answer is really close, be specific! Good Job!

Comment: Check it now. :)

Comment: Much closer, what is the internet made of, what makes it up. A job is based on this.

Comment: Lol. Does that makes it right? Tired of updates.

Comment: Your other answer was much closer. The answer is C___

Comment: Its done I guess

Comment: Correct answer my friend. Good job.